# Por que uma sessão de fotografia é chamada de "ensaio" fotográfico?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem

Que eu saiba, e pelo que os dicionários confirmam, um “ensaio” é um teste, um treino, algo feito de forma não definitiva. Mas o estranho é que é comum ver sendo dito pela mídia que “artista tal fez um ensaio fotográfico com alguém ou de algum jeito”.

Mas por que “ensaio”? Qual o sentido desse termo para uma sessão fotográfica?

Comment: Acho que isso não se usa em Portugal.

Comment: Yuuza, encontrei exemplos mais antigos que, creio, documentam o aparecimento do termo no Brasil e comprovam que ele foi adaptação do inglês.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Ensaio fotográfico*** é uma adaptação do inglês ***photographic essay***, que o [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photo%E2%80%93essay) define como:

> a group of photographs (as in a book or magazine) arranged to explore a theme or tell a story
> [um conjunto de fotografias (tal como num livro ou revista) organizadas para explorar um tema ou contar uma história (tradução minha)]

Este é também o sentido original em português. O sentido ’sessão fotográfica’ é um desenvolvimento posterior. Quando respondi a esta pergunta pela primeira vez, não encontrei *ensaio fotográfico* em dicionário nenhum, mas agora o sentido original já vem, ainda que algo disfarçadamente, no [(Periberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ensaio):

> **9.** Obra ou conjunto de obras que trata determinado tema sem contudo pretender ser exaustivo (ex. *ensaio fotográfico; ensaio visual*).

Tudo começou no francês *essai*, que há uns séculos, tal como *ensaio*, significava primeiramente ‘tentativa, teste’. Mas com a publicação em 1580 dos *Essais* de Montaigne (ver [CNTRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/essai)), seguidos na década seguinte pelos *Essays* de Francis Bacon, nasceu o género literário que veio a ser designado em português por *ensaio*(ver [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensaio_(literatura))), e que o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) define como:

> **9** LIT prosa livre que versa sobre tema específico, sem esgotá-lo, reunindo dissertações menores, menos definitivas do que as de um tratado formal, feito em profundidade <*ensaio sobre a violência*>

Em [“O conceito de ensaio fotográfico” (2008)](http://www.uel.br/revistas/uel/index.php/discursosfotograficos/article/view/1511/1257), Beatriz Fiuza e Cristiana Parente explicam que o ensaio fotográfico resulta da aplicação destas noções a obras constituídas essencialmente por fotografias: o ensaio fotográfico e o ensaio literário têm em comum o serem obras de caráter tentativo.

Segundo o [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photo%E2%80%93essay), o termo *photo-essay* é conhecido desde 1944. Não demorou muito a chegar ao Brasil. Em novembro de 1954 a revista norte-americana *Life* lançou o concurso [“A Photographic Essay—A Chance for Amanteurs”](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qVIEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22life%20photo%20essay%22%20rio&source=bl&ots=CcFNI5fhmX&sig=Afb8dK1tmCusg2QIRnqyZVlvdJo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif5fXQwereAhXEgpAKHda6DeEQ6AEwCnoECCQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22life%20photo%20essay%22%20rio&f=false), e o jornal carioca *Correio da Manhã* divulgou-o, traduzindo *photographich essay* por *ensaio fotográfico* (grafia original; negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Uma oportunidade excepcional aos fotógrafos amadores do mundo inteiro, é o que a revista “Life” está oferecendo atualmente. Trata-se de um concurso sôbre um **ensaio fotográfico** de tema livre, que deverá ser apresentado à Photographic Society of America — Life Photo Essay Contest […]
> É difícil explicar detalhadamente aos leitores em que consiste o **ensaio fotográfico**, mas o próprio “Life”, como exemplo, publicou 17 fotografias de cenas típicas do Rio de Janeiro, dando portanto uma orientação geral sobre o assunto.
> [“Concurso ‘Life’”, *Correio da Manhã*, Rio de Janeiro, 9 de janeiro de 1955](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=089842_06&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20195&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=43961)

Seis anos mais tarde, o termo continuava pouco conhecido. O [*Diário de Notícias* (Rio de Janeiro, 1961)](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093718_04&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20196&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=15292) refere-se a um artigo da *Life* por “[e]sse **ensaio fotográfico**, como o denominou «Life»”. Foi a partir de meados dos anos 60 que o termo se tornou frequente na imprensa brasileira, como designação das reportagens fotográficas que publicavam. Para isso muito contribuiu a revista paulistana [*Realidade* (exemplo de dezembro de 1966)](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=213659&Pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pagfis=1243):

> Nestas páginas, um **ensaio fotográfico** de David Drew Zingg e alguns dos maiores poetas brasileiros mostram por que poesia é mulher

(Clicando em “<< Matchs >>” permite navegar pelos vários “ensaios fotográficos” da revista.) Come este exemplo mostra, o ensaio fotográfico pode incluir textos curtos. O conceito chegou entretanto também a Portugal:

> O *Espaço Entre Nós*: um **ensaio fotográfico** sobre o que divide os portugueses
>
> […] colecção de mais de 20 imagens como “um artigo de opinião sob formato de fotografia”. “É um diário visual da sociedade portuguesa actual, não exaustivo e em contínua progressão, de como nos vamos tratando uns aos outros no terceiro país mais pacífico do mundo.”
> [Ana Marques Maia, *Publico*, 15 de outubro de 2018](https://www.publico.pt/2018/10/15/p3/fotogaleria/o-espaco-entre-nos-um-ensaio-fotografico-sobre-o-que-divide-os-portugueses-390593)

Entretanto, diz-nos [“O conceito de ensaio fotográfico” (2008)](http://www.uel.br/revistas/uel/index.php/discursosfotograficos/article/view/1511/1257), o termo *ensaio fotográfico* banalizou-se, sendo “interpretado pela maioria como uma simples união de fotografias sobre o mesmo tema ou realizadas por um mesmo autor” (p. 163).

### O sentido ’sessão fotográfica’

Em 2008, portanto, as autoras parecem não estar a par do sentido ’sessão fotográfica’. Mas já se encontra esse sentido na imprensa brasileira a parir de 1994: uma fotógrafa falando das suas sessões fotográficas diz que “um ensaio fotográfico dura uma tarde” ([*Folha de Hoje*, Caxias do Sul, 1994](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=882364&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20199&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=53299)); a fotografada que se apaixonou por um par de botas que usou “durante um ensaio fotográfico” ([*A Tribuna*, São Paulo, 2000](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=153931_05&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20200&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=7141)); dois capas de revista que “contam como foi o ensaio ortográfico” ([*Correio do Povo*, Jaguará do Sul (SC), 2001](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=886440&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20199&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=47767)).

Alguns destes casos poderão ter simplesmente resultado de uma omissão informal de algo como *produção de* ― “[a produção de] um ensaio fotográfico dura uma tarde”, “contam como foi [a produção d’] o ensaio fotográfico”. Mas é claro, veja-se a resposta do MWG Fotógrafo, que *ensaio fotográfico* passou a ser usado com sentido ’sessão fotográfica’ (pelo menos de certo tipo); não é simplesmente a omissão de *produção de* ou algo desse tipo. O surgimento deste novo sentido poderá ter sido facilitado por nalguns contextos o termo poder ser ambíguo.

Por exemplo quando [*A Tribuna* (São Paulo, 1993)](https://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=153931_04&pesq=%22ensaio%20fotogr%C3%A1fico%22&pasta=ano%20199&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=77029) diz que a famosa fotógrafa Marilyn Bridges “escolheu Cubatão para o próximo ensaio fotográfico”, quem não conheça o sentido original poderá facilmente pensar que o “ensaio fotográfico” se refere às sessões de fotografia, possivelmente com um modelo qualquer; enquanto *A Tribuna* poderá muito bem ter querido dizer que ela escolheu Cubatão para tema do ensaio fotográfico, que a fotógrafa iria depois expor ou publicar algures.

Comment: *[photo essay](https://www.google.pt/search?q=photo+essay&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=MPx&channel=fs&biw=1631&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMs6uB3u3NAhULtBQKHegYBeoQ_AUIBigB)* é a primeira vez que vejo, costumo ver *[photo shoot](https://www.google.pt/search?q=photo+essay&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=MPx&channel=fs&biw=1631&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMs6uB3u3NAhULtBQKHegYBeoQ_AUIBigB#newwindow=1&channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=photo+shoot)*

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas de acordo com o Merriam-Webster, *photo essay* são as fotos organizadas num álbum (vê na resposta), enquanto [photo shoot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photo%20shoot) é que é a sessão fotográfica. Em português é que *ensaio fotográfico* é usado nos dois sentidos.

Comment: "Por que uma **sessão de fotografia** é chamada de “ensaio” fotográfico?" Então não vejo a lógica de ter influência de *photo essay*

Comment: @JorgeB. A influência de *photo essay* foi diretamente em *ensaio fotográfico* no 1º sentido, album organizado para explorar um tema. *Ensaio* é também o equivalente a *essay* no sentido literário. Depois passar a usar *ensaio fotográfico* para designar *sessão fotográfica* é que é mais abusivo. Mas estas transições acontecem. Eu imagino coisas do tipo, alguém diz «o Silva fez um «ensaio fotográfico magnífico», querendo dizer, *álbum magnífico*, e o pessoal começar a entender em *ensaio* não só o álbum mas também o ato de fotografar por detrás do álbum.

Comment: Jacinto é uma teoria, mas não me convenceu.

Comment: @JorgeB. O que é que não te convenceu? (a) Que *ensaio fotográfico* no sentido de "álbum" seja uma adaptação direta de *photo essay*? Ou (b) que o sentido de sessão f. se tenha desenvolvido de alguma maneira a partir do sentido de "álbum"? Não há dúvida que o sentido original de *ensaio f.* foi "álbum", que corresponde exatamente, na forma e no significado, a *photo essay*. Mais tarde começou a usar-se *ensaio f.* com o sentido de sessão f. Parece-me que seria muito curioso que este novo uso se tivesse desenvolvido independentemente do original.

Comment: Jacinto com a edição que fizeste já fiquei mais convencido que tens razão no que dizes.

Comment: @JorgeB. Excelente. Ainda bem que fizeste aquele comentário. A função dos comentários também é esta: permitir ao autor da resposta ver onde onde é que o argumento pode ser melhorado. Entretanto entrei em contacto com fotógrafos profissionais. Estou a recolher perspetivas interessantes, que irei em breve incorporar na resposta.

Comment: @Jorge, creio que com a minha última edição vais ficar absolutamente convencido :)

Comment: @Jacinto "por nalguns contextos" significa algo como "porque em alguns contextos"?

Comment: @stafusa, significa exatamente isso: *nalguns* = *em alguns*. Com a diferença de *porque* introduzir uma subordinada finita (*pode ser*), enquanto *por* introduz uma subordinada reduzida de infinitivo (*poder ser*).

Comment: Obrigado, @Jacinto Nas primeiras leituras tive a forte impressão de que a frase estava truncada, mas na verdade é perfeitamente normal.

Answer (score 2):

Assim como num Tubo de ensaio de laboratório, quando se faz testes para observar na prática o resultado, pode-se chegar a um resultado ou não.
Por isso a nomenclatura tubo de ensaio, ou tubo de testes.

Uma sessão fotográfica, permite qualquer tipo de fotografia, em um determinado tempo.

Um ensaio fotográfico, não será um ensaio se for feito por modelo profissional (para modelos profissionais, se utiliza o termo book, como portfólio profissional). Um ensaio é o termo específico para fotos construídas dentro de um único tema, e por pessoas comuns, que não são profissionais. Caso o ensaio não fique bom, poderá ser repetido. Diferente de um casamento que é um momento único, não tem ensaio.

Espero ter ajudado na definição mais plausível para o termo ENSAIO FOTOGRÁFICO no Brasil. MWG

Answer (score -2):

**SINÔNIMOS PARA FOTOGRAFIA.**
Sinônimos de Fotografia são usados por todos os lados.
Ensaio fotográfico pode não ser o mais correto dado a língua portuguesa e seus sinônimos referentes a fotografia. 
Mas, trata-se de uso comum, e por si já carrega o status de "correto" assim como:

- Tomar uma coca, como sinônimo de tomar um refrigerante.
- Tirar uma Xérox ao invés de fotocopiar algo.

Espero que tenha dado a minha contribuição para os tais sinônimos da fotografia hoje em dia.